# Normalise relation

Tags: relational-database, normalization, relation

I want to normalize this on 1NF, 2NF and 3NF.
I know a little bit how to normalize tables in practice but I don't know where to start using letters. Thanks

```
R (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)

AB -> C
A -> DE
B -> F
F -> GH
D -> IJ
```

```
L: A, B

M: D, F

R: C, E, G, H, I, J

AB*
ABC
ABCDE
ABCDEF
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

How to find the primary key here?

Comment: Is this a homework question? What are the letters? Show us your progress.

Comment: yeah. Its given the relation with the following functions. that is the whole exercise. I havent done any progress yet. sorry.

Comment: Ok let us know when you do, against policy to to do homework for people without any attempt.

Comment: Hey I made some progress. Can U please check it.. Thanks @PhilipDevine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always start checking with the lowest normal form and move upwards. If you are not given what these letters stand for then you have to assume that *it is in **1NF***.
 
**To check 2NF:** 
 The key here is **AB**. 2NF is **violated** when given a functional dependency ***X->Y*** if *right-hand side* is *non-prime* and is not part of *X* and *left-hand side* is a proper subset of a key (which here is **AB**). So here you can directly see one of the functional dependencies **A->DE** violating this and hence it is not in **2NF**. Now move on to check for **3NF**. As it appears to be a homework question, I will be willing to help you any further only once you show some progress on that.
I will suggest you to watch [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMB6UC_ItN4&list=PL009B833078C3C571) videos. (*especially 28a and 29a*). This should get you started!

Comment: Thank you so much. I definitely will watch those.

Comment: Hey check my updated question. Now Why AB is the primary key? Is It always the X in the first equation? I mean in the first X->Y Can there be more than one key? @PuRaK

Comment: `AB` is the key because `AB* = ABCDEFGHI` (i.e. all the attributes of the relation). **No** it is not always the X in the first equation. **Yes** there can be more than one key.

Comment: Hey I m sorry I dont understand why AB is the key. Can u explain it a little further or maybe with a short example? @PuRak

Comment: `AB` is  a key because **AB-closure (AB*)** gives all the attributes of the relation. I suggest you watch 20a to undestand **X closure**.

Comment: I will see it now. These videos are helping me a lot thanks. @PuRaK